# MySQL using WHERE and OR

Tags: php, mysql

I am allowing people to input either their username, account number or email address before typing their password, so i need to compare their input against 3 fields in my table but i am not getting any results.

i first tried this ...

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM useraccounts WHERE username='$thisuser' or accnum='$thisuser' or email='$thisuser'");
```

then i read on here that brackets should be placed around OR statements, so tried this ...

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM useraccounts WHERE (username='$thisuser' or accnum='$thisuser' or email='$thisuser')");
```

but neither work, can someone help please

just for comparison, this does work when i type in the username value ...

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM useraccounts WHERE username='$thisuser'");
```

Comment: Please paste the rest the rest of the code. Does `$thisuser` contain the correct value? Are you sure it exists in the database?

Comment: Could you print `$result` ?

Comment: The brackets are not needed there (you use them to force operator precedence, which would be required if you needed to check for a match on any of those fields AND the password). But both those queries look fine from a syntax point of view.

Comment: Please setup JSfiddle with data... statement looks good

Comment: try to assign the sql-command in some var and print it. Your code is ok. The bug is not here.

Comment: @DanFromGermany i think you are try to say setup SQLfiddle right ?

Comment: you should start by quoting your values correctly into the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the datatype of accnum? Are you sure it is varchar?

If accnum is of type **numeric** then try

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM useraccounts WHERE (username='$thisuser' or accnum=$thisuser or email='$thisuser')");
```

Comment: it is numeric, and i have tried your code but still no joy

Comment: Have you tried executing the same query on mysql? and if you have allready tried that can you share some more code here, and make sure that $thisuser is not empty

Comment: yeah $this user has a value, i mentioned this in my original post - however i have made my accnum into a CHAR and it all seems ok now

Comment: try printing your query in php like

`$qstr="SELECT * FROM useraccounts WHERE (username='$thisuser' or accnum=$thisuser or email='$thisuser')";
print $qstr;

$res=mysqli_query($con,$qstr);`

This may give you a hint what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Seems no problem. Please check '$thisuser' has value. Try printing the sql statement.
You may try running query directly on database.

Answer (score 0):

I also think first check the value of `$thisuser`, and then try below query

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM useraccounts WHERE (username='".$thisuser."' or accnum='".$thisuser."' or email='".$thisuser."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Rathere then using at server side if it done at client side in js file by checking it emailid or username oraccount number according to that u can pass value

Comment: how can it client check without first accessing the database to make a comparison ?